# The transaction log for database [database-name] is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using Microsoft SQL Sever 2014 and executed a stored procedure having larger data for the insert operation. After 3 hours of execution, I got this error

> The transaction log for database [database-name] is full due to ACTIVE_TRANSACTION

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Screenshot attached for the database size details.

[image]

Comment: hi, can you share more details like size of data and operation?

Comment: "having larger data for the insert operation" this makes no sense to me. But more info can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674973/the-transaction-log-for-the-database-is-full

Comment: @jainvikram444 - added as per your request.

Comment: Have you installed all sql-server updates? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3095156/fix-error-9002-and-error-3052-when-you-try-to-add-or-back-up-log-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The transaction log for the database is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674973/the-transaction-log-for-the-database-is-full)

Comment: Thanks team...your reference solved my problem....